# Revert the `--no-site-packages` option with virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have created a virtualenv using the `--no-site-packages` option and installed lots of libraries. Now I would like to revert the `--no-site-packages` option and use also the global packages.

Can I do that without recreating the virtualenv?

**More precisely:**

I wonder what *exactly* happens when creating a virtualenv using the `--no-site-packages` option as opposed to not using that option.

If I know what happens then I can figure out how to undo it.

Comment: [an other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433198/) was marked as duplicate of this one, and it received an answer which might be interesting here too.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Try removing (or renaming) the file `no-global-site-packages.txt` in your `Lib` folder under your virtual environment.

Where **venv** is the name of your virtual environment, and **python3.4** corresponds to whichever version of python involved, for example:

```
$ rm venv/lib/python3.4/no-global-site-packages.txt
```

And if you change your mind and want to put it back:

```
$ touch venv/lib/python3.4/no-global-site-packages.txt
```

**Note:** If you don't see the above file, then you have a newer version of virtualenv. You'll want to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58513801/21539) instead

Comment: That will do it. The existence (or nonexistence) of that file is the only direct effect of the no-site-packages flag. Virtualenv's customized site.py looks for that file to decide whether to add global site-packages directories to sys.path.

Comment: Brilliant! That did it! Thanks a lot for that answer, and thanks to Carl Meyer for the additional comment.

Comment: that's `virtualenv/python2.7/no-global-site-packages.txt` in my ubuntu server.

Comment: Windows version of virtualenv contains `virtualenv/pyenv.cfg` file. There is one option for site-packages: 
`include-system-site-packages = false` 
Change this value and call Activate.ps1

Comment: @georgik - that also works for Linux version of `venv` for `Python 3.4`.

Comment: This does not work with Anaconda virtual environments.

Comment: This file doesn't seem to appear anymore.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58513801/21539 for a updated answer

Comment: Obsolete answer

Answer (score 35):

At least for Python 3.5.2, there is `pyvenv.cfg` file in the root of virtualenv directory. All you need to do is to change `include-system-site-packages` flag from `false` to `true`:

```
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = false  # <- change this to "true"
version = 3.5.2
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, I was going mad trying to do the reverse (get a venv to let programs use the global packages) and it seems the venv is created by default with this set to false

Answer (score 23):

Go to your venv folder and open `pyvenv.cfg`. (E.g. if your virtual environment is called `myenv` then the file will be located at `myenv\pyvenv.cfg`)

You'll see a boolean setting called `include-system-site-packages`

Set that setting to `true` to use global packages

If you want to disable using global packages, just set that setting to `false` instead.

Comment: Upvoting this for higher visibility. Should be accepted answer, because most users have latest venv running.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the three-years-earlier [answer by kotrfa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972692/95852).

Answer (score 12):

When using [virtualenvwrapper](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper) to manage virtualenvs, you can use the shell function `toggleglobalsitepackages` to switch between using and not using site packages.

Comment: This only works with older versions (not sure when this changed), when virtualenv still used the existance of `no-global-site-packages.txt` as the flag. Newer versions use a setting in the file pyvenv.cfg instead. It seems that virtualenv_wrapper has not been updated to work with this change to virtualenv https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/issues/345/toggleglobalsitepackages-command-seems.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a symlink between `/virtualenv_root/lib/` and `/path/to/desired/site-packages/`

Comment: +1 This works on my system (openSUSE Linux 12.3, Python 2.7.3, virtualenv 1.8.4); I don't have a `no-global-site-packages.txt` anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Where 'myvenv' is the name of your virtual environment, and python3.8, like mine, for example, all you need to do in command line is:

```
$ python3 -m venv --system-site-packages myvenv
```

Comment: The question is asking for a solution "without recreating the virtualenv".