# GotoBLAS error when installing matplotlib with pip in a virtualenv on debian wheezy

Tags: matplotlib, debian, virtualenv, pip, blas

I'm trying to install matplotlib with pip in a virtualenv on debian wheezy.
And i get the following message:

```
Running setup.py egg_info for package matplotlib
    GotoBLAS : Architecture Initialization failed. No initialization function found.
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.3.1]
                    python: yes [2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14)  [GCC
                            4.7.2]]
                  platform: yes [linux2]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    GotoBLAS : Architecture Initialization failed. No initialization function found.

============================================================================

Edit setup.cfg to change the build options



BUILDING MATPLOTLIB

            matplotlib: yes [1.3.1]

                python: yes [2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14)  [GCC

                        4.7.2]]

              platform: yes [linux2]



REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS

----------------------------------------
```

I previously had `libopenblas-dev` installed. In fact, I managed to install matplotlib in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 using the same procedure.
Any ideas?

## Update 1:

I finally installed matplotlib from the distribution packages. Then based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571454/virtualenv-specifing-which-packages-to-use-system-wide-vs-local) I created an environment using the flag `--system-site-packages`.
To test the installation I tried to import matplotlib in python:

```
>>> import matplotlib
GotoBLAS : Architecture Initialization failed. No initialization function found.
```

But I get the same error :( .

## Update 2:

I found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/theano-users/SbH4l6zreLU/BK_PGiY9J9UJ). It is the same error and it was on KVM, just like me. Maybe this error is related with KVM?
I just installed matplotlib without problems in debian wheezy running over VirtualBox. But I really need to install it on the KVM machine.

## Update 3:

The same error occurs when trying to import numpy in the same system:

```
>>> import numpy
GotoBLAS : Architecture Initialization failed. No initialization function found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution! I followed the procedure in [Daniel Nouri's Blog](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2012/12/19/libblas-and-liblapack-issues-and-speed,-with-scipy-and-ubuntu/).

Here's a summary:

Install `libatlas3-base`:

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base
```

Use `liblapack3.so.3` from `/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3` as your default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge libopenblas-dev
```