# Unable to import numpy: Error: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas

Tags: python, numpy, lapack, blas, openblas

When I try to import numpy, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py in <module>()
     49 from .info import __doc__
     50 
---> 51 from .linalg import *
     52 
     53 from numpy.testing import Tester

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in <module>()
     27     )
     28 from numpy.lib import triu, asfarray
---> 29 from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
     30 from numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix import matrix_power
     31 from numpy.compat import asbytes

ImportError: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas
```

I have already tried solutions posted [Error by import numpy: lapack_lite.so: undefined symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612728/error-by-import-numpy-lapack-lite-so-undefined-symbol) and [GotoBLAS error when installing matplotlib with pip in a virtualenv on debian wheezy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058653/gotoblas-error-when-installing-matplotlib-with-pip-in-a-virtualenv-on-debian-whe)

I already tried all the options in:

```
vvkulkarni@galileo:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3
There are 3 choices for the alternative liblapack.so.3 (providing /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3).

  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/openblas-base/liblapack.so.3      40        auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3   35        manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3             10        manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/openblas-base/liblapack.so.3      40        manual mode
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.1 and python 2.7

Comment: how did you install numpy? Your problem is more than likely having conflicting `liblapack.so.3` I only have `/usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3` running ubuntu 14.04. Can you remove `libopenblas-base`?

Comment: I installed it using apt-get install:sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose

Comment: You could also try using pip but may well get the same issue, I had no issue installing the `scipy-stack` originally

Comment: I tried that too but hit this and the workaround provided does not work for me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a

Comment: are you on a mac or using ubuntu?

Comment: I am on ubuntu for sure... to be clear things were working fine until a system apt-upgrade was done to patch for shellshock after which I am hitting these issues.

Comment: so numpy was working before the upgrade?

Comment: Yes it was working before the upgrade.

Comment: Yeah I did try to reinstall

Comment: This is surprising. I removed libopenblas-base, reinstalled libatlas3-dev and now the error goes away. But now I have a slower numpy :(. I believe OpenBLAS is much faster

Comment: Yes, I did mention that in my first comment ;) Well the numpy you have now is definitely faster than the one you had a few minutes ago!

Comment: Indeed ! A working numpy is better than no numpy at all :). Thanks !

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working

Comment: The workaround by Padraic worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To solve these issues, I followed the install bash script here: https://gist.github.com/amirsani/d2aa0763cc138902bf73

I still had the same error occur during testing at the ending of all the installation so I did this

```
sudo apt-get remove libopenblas-base
```

Which I got from here: [Installing lapack for numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917977/installing-lapack-for-numpy)

This appears to have solved my original problem (similar to yours but not identical) where I was attempting to run the following from ipython

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
```

which produced an identical error to the one you had.

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that your numpy installation is in '/usr/**local**/lib', but apt-get will put numpy in '/usr/lib'. This suggests to me that you have another copy of numpy which was installed by another method (e.g. `pip install`). Check if you have a directory called `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/`. If so, you just need to make sure that Python imports numpy from here and not from '/usr/local/lib'.

Try deleting, renaming or moving the directory `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/`, alternatively you can change `sys.path` from within Python.