# Python_packages, MATLAB and yaafe_extensions directories not created after installing YAAFE

Tags: audio, installation, feature-extraction

I'm following [this](http://yaafe.sourceforge.net/manual/install.html#debian-ubuntu-packages) page to install Yaafe. After 'make install' the following directories should be found under my installation directory. But only the first 3 are present. MATLAB, python_packages, and yaafe_extensions directories are not present. Does anyone know what could be the reason?

```
INSTALL_DIR/bin/               
INSTALL_DIR/include/            
INSTALL_DIR/lib/       
INSTALL_DIR/matlab/         
INSTALL_DIR/python_packages/   
INSTALL_DIR/yaafe_extensions/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are easy ways to install YAAFE. The best way for me is probably through conda. Various ways to install yaafe is given in the link. 
http://yaafe.github.io/Yaafe/manual/install.html

After installation when I tried to import yaafelib and yaafefeatures in ipython i kept getting this error repeatedly.

**ERROR: cannot load yaafe component library "libyaafe-components.so" !
/usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088411/unable-to-import-numpy-error-usr-lib-liblapack-so-3-undefined-symbol-gotobl/43536848#43536848) link I found out that I had 2 instances of Numpy installed. Then I removed Numpy as pip uninstall numpy.

I also had to remove libopenblas-base as sudo apt-get remove libopenblas-base.

The errors stopped then.