# Import caffe/scipy error: liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: sgetrs_N_single

Tags: python, scipy, caffe, lapack

I installed Caffe on a stock Ubuntu 16.04 system running on a Jetson TX1.
It was running fine until I compiled and installed OpenBlas, then started getting this error in importing caffe in Python 2:

```
>>> import caffe

[ Large stack backtrace omitted]

from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: sgetrs_N_single
```

I was able to get back running by using this command:

> sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3

and choosing the *liblapack.so.3* in */usr/lib*, not in */usr/lib/openblas-base*.

I'd rather not have to do this each time I install OpenBlas.  I've Googled for this error, but didn't see any solutions come up.   Anyone see this?

Comment: I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088411/unable-to-import-numpy-error-usr-lib-liblapack-so-3-undefined-symbol-gotobl)

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the [source](https://docs.rs/crate/openblas-src/0.5.0/source/source/lapack/getrs/Makefile) of openblas, it looks like this symbol is used in a Makfile for building `getrs`.

It appears that this library is missing a set of underlying binaries. `sgetrs_N_single` is the first in the makefile, but I suspect if it were removed you would get the same error next for `sgetrs_T_single`. When the shared library looks for this sub-component, it can't find it. I suspect something went wrong too quietly in the build or there is a step missing in the build instructions.

Comment: I'll try rebuilding OpenBlas, being careful to include all optional packages.  I'll update with the results.