# installing PyGObject via pip in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pygobject, gio

I'm actually upgrading an old django app from python2.7 to python3.4. While installing pygobject via pip, I got this error:

```
Collecting pygobject
  Using cached pygobject-2.28.3.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9dp0wn96/pygobject/setup.py", line 272
        raise SystemExit, 'ERROR: Nothing to do, gio could not be found and is essential.'
                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9dp0wn96/pygobject
```

I am trying to install it in a virtualenv. System-wide installation doesn't work either... I am working on arch linux with python3.4

I have installed the arch package named pygobject-devel 3.16.2-1 but I still can't import gobject python module

What is this damned missing gio?

Any help is welcomed...
Thanx in advance !

Comment: It could be that you only need to install gi, but I am not sure about it and can't install PyGObject in my virtualenv either.

Comment: Ok,j I managed to install pyGObject, system-wide with a pre-compiled package, which is the easier way (extra/python-gobject2). The upper error is a simple Syntax error, because setup.py for this pip package is only designed for Windows anyway... I have to run some tests and experiment to manage to use it in virtualenv.

Comment: According to [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38219461/339144) this is now possible. I did not check this myself.

Comment: @KlaasvanSchelven You're right ! Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ANSWER IS NOW IN THE POST TAGGED IN COMMENT ABOVE !!!!
Have a look there => [Python cannot install PyGObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862049/python-cannot-install-pygobject/38219461#38219461)**

Ok I just managed it !

To install PyGObject in virtrualenv, give up with pip.

1. Install PyGObject system-wide (with your package manager or compile it manually). For example, in my case :

   ```
   sudo pacman -Suy python-gobject2
   ```
2. Link it in your virtualenv :

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gobject* /WHEREVER/IS/YOUR/VIRTUALENV/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
   ```
3. You might need to link some other modules (in my case glib) :

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/glib* /WHEREVER/IS/YOUR/VIRTUALENV/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
   ```

You might find some helpful infos about system-wide and virtualenv installations and interactions between modules here :

[virtualenv: Specifing which packages to use system-wide vs local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571454/virtualenv-specifing-which-packages-to-use-system-wide-vs-local)

Comment: I've made vext to automate this.    If you have pygobject installed in the system then you can install vext.gi in the virtualenv.

Comment: Thx @StuartAxon, vext is a great lil' helper.