# Python cannot install PyGObject

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip, pygobject

I try install pygobject by pip

```
pip install --user PyGObject
```

but I doesn't work:

```
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached pygobject-2.28.3.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-phby_jwb\PyGObject\
setup.py", line 272
        raise SystemExit, 'ERROR: Nothing to do, gio could not be found and is
 essential.'
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-phby_jwb\PyGObject
```

My python version v3.5.0:374f501f4567,
Now I work on windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upstream PyGObject just does not support this. See the [PyGObject win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/) project or the [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) project to get it easily.

Answer (score 9):

## For windows

1. Go to http://www.msys2.org/ and download the x86_64 installer
2. Follow the instructions on the page for setting up the basic environment
3. Run `C:\msys64\mingw32.exe` - a terminal window should pop up
4. Execute `pacman -Suy`
5. Execute `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gtk3 mingw-w64-i686-python3-gobject`
6. To test that GTK 3 is working you can run `gtk3-demo`
7. Copy the `hello.py` script you created to `C:\msys64\home\<username>`
8. In the mingw32 terminal execute `python3 hello.py` - a window should appear.

---

## For ubuntu / Debian

### **Installing the system provided PyGObject**:

1. Open a terminal
2. Execute `sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0`
3. Change the directory to where your `hello.py` script can be found (e.g. `cd Desktop`)
4. Run `python3 hello.py`

### **Installing from PyPI with pip**:

1. Open a terminal and enter your virtual environment
2. Execute
   `sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0`
3. Execute `pip3 install pycairo` to build and install Pycairo
4. Execute `pip3 install PyGObject` to build and install PyGObject
5. Change the working directory to where your `hello.py` script can be found
6. Run `python3 hello.py`

---

#### You can read more [*here*](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#ubuntu-logo-ubuntu-debian-logo-debianhere)

Comment: sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0 | this worked for me, on ubuntu:latest

Answer (score 8):

Since February 2017, you can install pygobject directly through pip: `pip install pygobject`. It requires some packages to be installed though.

Before that, it took a while, but it was possible to install pygobject with pip, since [this commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/commit/?id=f65bb1fc8f7f6172970545412fe56ab75f57904b).

pygobject wasn't on pypi though, so you had to specify the git or tarball URL:

- `git+https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject`
- `https://download.gnome.org/sources/pygobject/3.22/pygobject-3.22.0.tar.xz`

The latter only works with pygobject 3.22+, which should have happenned [around mid-september 2016](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointTwentyone). (3.21.1 should be the first pip-installable development release)

Comment: I tried these two methods that you specified and couldn't install it though!

Comment: i get an error that says "error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add what I've been using to make this work seamlessly in various projects.

It uses *GNU Make*, by providing a `venv` target one can use as a dependency to other targets to ensure a properly created virtual environment.

The `venv` target itself depends on a, albeit configurable, `requirements.txt`; the standard python requirements file.

A target `test` is include as an example of how one would use this.

The trick is to create a symlink to the installed system package. `ln -s ${DIST_PACKAGES}/gi ${VENV_NAME}/lib/python${PYTHON_VER}/site-packages/gi`, where `$DIST_PACKAGE` is the location of the python installed libraries on your system.

For those not familiar with make. Create a file named `Makefile` in the root of your project, copy the contents bellow, and issue the command `make configure && make venv`.

Makefile

```
# directory to store virtual environment
VENV_NAME=venv

# python runtime version
PYTHON_VER=3.6

# python executble
PYTHON=${VENV_NAME}/bin/python${PYTHON_VER}

# python local libraries location
DIST_PACKAGES=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

# pip requirements file
REQUIREMENTS=requirements.txt

configure:      ## Install required debian packages.
    sudo apt-get -y install python${PYTHON_VER} python3-pip libgirepository1.0-dev
    python3 -m pip install virtualenv pygobject
    make venv

venv:           ## Recreates the virtual environment if needed.
venv: $(VENV_NAME)/bin/activate
$(VENV_NAME)/bin/activate: ${REQUIREMENTS}
    test -d $(VENV_NAME) || virtualenv -p python${PYTHON_VER} $(VENV_NAME)
    ${PYTHON} -m pip install -U pip
    ${PYTHON} -m pip install -r ${REQUIREMENTS}
    ln -s ${DIST_PACKAGES}/gi ${VENV_NAME}/lib/python${PYTHON_VER}/site-packages/gi
    touch $@

test:           ## Runs the test suite.
test: venv
    $(PYTHON) -m pytest tests
```