# pip3 install pygobject ERROR: Nothing to do, gio could not be found and is essential

Tags: python, macos, pygobject

I want to install pygobject for **python3** on mac OSX

```
pip3 install pygobject
```

It raises an error below:

```
$ pip3 install pygobject
Collecting pygobject
  Using cached pygobject-2.28.3.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/xxxx/pip-build-m79wzagx/pygobject/setup.py", line 272
        raise SystemExit, 'ERROR: Nothing to do, gio could not be found and is essential.'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862049/python-cannot-install-pygobject ?

Comment: To add to that for OSX see options like homebrew, macports, or jhbuild to build pygobject and friends.

Answer (score 2):

This python3 **pygobject package** requires **pygobject3**, install the pygobject3 on Mac OSX first:

```
$ brew install pygobject3 --with-python3

$ pip3 install pygobject
```