# Setting up a PyCharm environment for a GTK Hello World on Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, pygtk

I'm just trying to make a simple GTK Hello World app run in Pycharm.

- I have installed [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) 2016.2.
- I have installed any combination of [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) (Python 2, Python 3, 32 bit, 64 bit).
- I have downloaded a [GTK hello world example](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/helloworld.py)

When I try to run this stuff, I first get the error

```
C:\Users\[...]\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/[...]/PycharmProjects/HelloTk/hellotk.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/[...]/PycharmProjects/HelloTk/hellotk.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygtk
ImportError: No module named 'pygtk'
```

Which I tried to resolve by the instructions on SO: [How do I import modules in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm). However, this does not work for the error

```
Collecting PyGTK
  Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Could not import dsextras module: Make sure you have installed pygobject.
```

Which brought me to the next step, installing `pygobject`. At first, this failed because of a missing `pkg-config`, which I installed according the instructions on Stack Overflow [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363820/480982). This seemed to work, but I now get the error

```
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached pygobject-2.28.3.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    * glib-2.0.pc could not be found, bindings for glib._glib will not be built.
    ERROR: Nothing to do, glib could not be found and is essential.
```

Googling more, I found [Installing PygObject via PIP in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324430/installing-pygobject-via-pip-in-virtualenv), but the solution is for Linux only.

Since ~2h since I installed PyCharm and Anaconda I'm trying to compile a stupid simple Hello World program. How do I make it work and what was I doing wrong?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, there are [pre-built installers](http://pygtk.org/downloads.html) for Windows

Comment: Also GTK support is not that good on alternative OS' like Windows, so I'd rather use Linux distro for GTK based development if I were you.

Comment: Or switch to Qt instead of GTK for better cross-platform GUI support

Comment: @cricket_007: GTK was recommended somewhere on SO as the best cross-platform choice. If I find it again, I'll certainly downvote that

Comment: Maybe if you develop strictly within a Linux environment :D

Comment: make sure you are using Anconda's `pip` than `/usr/bin/python` (or windows equivalent) type in `which python` and run  `*which python location* -m pip install`

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the latest installer for windows from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar

Also, you must make sure you are not running python 3.5 or newer, the last supported version seems to be 3.4.x for GTK.

It took me a few hours to figure this out as the installer completes without complaining at all on 3.5 as well, it just doesn't install the package.

Regards,

Hunor

Edit: so, while this sort of works to install, i still can't get quite a few things to work in it :(