# mkvirtualenv: Specify which packages to inherit from system wide installation

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to inherit some system wide packages like `pep257`, `flake8` into my virtual environment when I am creating it.

What I currently do is that I have an environment called `base-env`. I have `pep257` and `flake8` setup in this environment and I use it like this

```
$ workon base-env
(base-env)$ cpvirtualenv base-env new-env
(new-env)$
```

Is there a better way than doing this?
I checked their [documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) but I couldn't find any option for that

**Related to `virtualenv` but not `mkvirtualenv`**

- [virtualenv: Specifing which packages to use system-wide vs local](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14571454/3834059)
- [Make virtualenv inherit specific packages from your global site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12079607/3834059)

**Edit**:

By **"a better way"** I mean, in which I don't have to do `cpvirtualenv`. The new environment should setup `pep257`, `flake8`(or any other package for the matter) automatically inside it when I create it.

Comment: *"better"* by what criteria, exactly? What's the problem with your current version? Why don't you just e.g. `pip install -r mybaserequirements.txt`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Edited the details of the question