# Is it possible to install older python packages in a virtual environment but still re-use system ones?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-import

I am wondering if is possible to use system packages unless I install never or older versions in my python virtual environment.

I want to avoid reinstalling some big packages (like numpy) in each virtual environment, especially because I have hundreds of them on the build server (lots of repositories * branches * builds * target-platforms).

Now the problem is that in some cases I may have to assure that my virtual environment is using a specific version of a package, like `botocore=1.3.9` and maybe my system python already has a newer version of the package and I want to be sure that when I import botocore, it will not use the system version, even if is newer. Still, I do want to use site-packages which are not installed in the virtual environment.

Is this possible, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtualenv: Specifing which packages to use system-wide vs local](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571454/virtualenv-specifing-which-packages-to-use-system-wide-vs-local)