# How to use the NumPy installed by Pacman in virtualenv?

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, archlinux-arm, pacman-package-manager

My system is Archlinux.
My project will use NumPy, and my project is in a virtual environment created by virtualenv.

As it is difficult to install NumPy by pip, I install it by Pacman:

`sudo pacman -S python-scikit-learn`

But how can I use it in virtualenv?

Comment: Why is it difficult to install it via pip? It should be quite straightforward if you have the necessary compilers, libraries etc. installed.

Comment: Agree with ThiefMaster. If you already have the required dependencies on your system from the pacman install, it should just be a case of pip install. It will be easier than messing with variables to use the system numpy. Unless you are happy to use all system libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` switch to use system-wide packages in addition to the ones installed in the stdlib.

Comment: Yes， this is a method. But if so, I have to uninstall the unnecessary lib. But in new version of virtualenv, pip uninstall can not work.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571454/virtualenv-specifing-which-packages-to-use-system-wide-vs-local)

Comment: Why do you care about unused libs? You can still install other versions inside the virtualenv if that's what you need.

Comment: OK, anyway, I will have a try.