# Installing caffe on virtualenv on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, ubuntu-20.04

I've made to installed it using the following command line:

> sudo apt install caffe-cpu

However, I can only import caffe on base environment, when I go to a virtualenv it gives error.
I'm not using Anaconda.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571454/virtualenv-specifing-which-packages-to-use-system-wide-vs-local.

Comment: It did help, thank you!