# virtualenv and pip | Pip does only installing to global path

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

i don't know why, but pip does only install to global path, although i'am working on a env:

```
macbook$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
macbook$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
macbook$ workon ivm
(ivm)macbook$ pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

But this Path is not the correct path of my virtualenv. I see don't way. What is a possible solution for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create the virtualenv with `--system-site-packages`?  If so, possible duplicate of [Make virtualenv inherit specific packages from your global site-packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages).

Comment: No I didn't. The env was working in the past without problems. i don't know what happens ...

Comment: If i activate export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true the terminal throws "Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).". Even if i create a new env it does not work.

Comment: Try upgrade your virtualenv and pip system-wide, then try again. E.g. `pip install -U pip` or `pip install -U virtualenv` Older versions may exhibit bugs.

Comment: Thank's for you answer. I had done this already. Both is upto-date. I can only execute pip currently with sudo otherwise it throws the "Could not find an activated virutalenv"...

Comment: Has anybody some ideas what i can do?