# Mix Python virtualenv packages with distro packages?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

What is a good way to handle the case when you use Python **virtualenv** but you want some of the packages installed via your distro's package manager?

Let's say you need **lxml** but because you can't get `pip install lxml` to work on Ubuntu. and you really don't want to waste time on this, so you just do a `apt-get install python-lxml`.

Now, you can create a virtaulenv with `--system-site-packages` and have access to the system-wide installed pre-compiled **lxml** now. But you'll also drag in all the other system wide packages that you don't need! And yes, there will be quite a bunch of packages that will be installed outside virtualenv, either via `sudo pip ...` or `sudo apt-get python-...`, so no **"just keep the system clean and install everything you can in virtualenvs, so that `--system-site-packages` won't drag too many packages with it"** is not a solution form me here.

So, **is there a way to install just *some particular* system-site-packages?**

Comment: Could you explain why is it problematic to have a virtualenv that has access to all system packages?

Comment: @Andrzej turns out I was a bit ignorant about what selurvedu just explained below (""Packages installed by pip in user's home directory have higher priority than system-wide packages, thus, they are taken first when doing import. In virtualenv, they are only imported if virtualenv was created with --system-site-packages option. Packages installed by pip inside virtualenv have even higher priority."). Knowing this, I see that it's not really problematic in my case, and if it ever will be, his answer still holds...

Comment: That's right, I have always successfully combined system-wide packages with locally installed with `pip install --user` and virtualenv. It is just important to realize the hierarchy of priorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use `pip install --user packagename` – it doesn't require sudo.

If you don't have `pip` yet, or either OS's `pip` or OS's `easy_install` doesn't work properly, first install `setuptools` in user's home directory, and then use its `easy_install` for `pip`.

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python3 - --user
$ easy_install-3.4 --user pip
```

On the other side, if you decide to use `pip` inside virtualenv, don't use `--user` option for an obvious reason.

---

### Doing it the way you described

For example, I want to import module `curl` that's present in OS.

```
$ pip3 install --user virtualenv
$ python3 -m virtualenv myvenv
$ cd myvenv
$ source bin/activate
(myvenv)$ python3
>>> import curl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named curl
```

There is no such module inside virtualenv. Just to make sure I looked into what's in `sys.path`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['',
'/home/username/myvenv/lib/python27.zip',
'/home/username/myvenv/lib/python2.7',
'/home/username/myvenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/home/username/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Notice that there is no `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages`, just as you wanted, but `/usr/lib/python3.4` is present. If that's not okay for you, use `--always-copy` option when creating a virtualenv.

In my further steps I create symbolic links to `curl` module and its dependencies.

```
>>> ^D # Press Control-D
(myvenv)$ ln -s /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/curl lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```

Notice that there is no trailing slash in the second argument (file or directory which symlink points to), but there is a slash in the third argument (where symlink should be created). That's because I create a symlink **inside** of the directory `lib/python3.4/site-packages`. Without a trailing slash, it would try to replace the directory.

Let's check if that works.

```
(myvenv)$ python3
>>> import curl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/curl/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sys, pycurl
ImportError: No module named 'pycurl'
```

Nope. `curl` depends on `pycurl`. We need to go deeper.

```
>>> ^D
(myvenv)$ ls -1 /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pycurl*
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pycurl-7.19.3.1-py3.4.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pycurl.cpython-34m.so
(myvenv)$ ln -s /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pycurl-7.19.3.1-py3.4.egg-info lib/python3.4/site-packages/
(myvenv)$ ln -s /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pycurl.cpython-34m.so lib/python3.4/site-packages/
(myvenv)$ python3
>>> import curl
>>> curl
<module 'curl' from '/home/username/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/curl/__init__.py'>
```

At last.

Is this what you need?

---

Personally, I strongly discourage you from doing this because, firstly, this is a perversion.

Moreover, I doubt this method works on everything. The depth of dependencies can be scary.

Secondly, I see no reason in avoiding `--system-site-packages` that works like a charm in all cases I'm acknowledged about.

Packages installed by `pip` in user's home directory have higher priority than system-wide packages, thus, they are taken first when doing `import`.
In virtualenv, they are only imported if virtualenv was created with `--system-site-packages` option.
Packages installed by `pip` inside virtualenv have even higher priority.

Honestly, I wrote this answer just to ask, **why** would you want to mess with all this instead of getting `pip` to work. I can't yet write comments on SO, so that's why I wrote a complete answer. :)

> But you'll also drag in all the other system wide packages that you don't need!

No, you won't. You load a module into memory only when doing `import`. If you mean the package will be present in virtualenv – once again, it won't. If you had looked inside of `myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/` you would have seen that there are only two packages inside - `pip` and `setuptools` (the latter one is separated into several directories though). The Python interpreter inside virtualenv simply loads system-wide modules just like an ordinary interpreter does.

---

P.S. The code above also applies to Python 2.7. Just replace `pip3` with `pip2`, `python3` with `python2`, `3.4` with `2.7`, etc.

P.P.S. Instead of symlinking, you can copy the modules with their dependencies into virtualenv to the corresponding directories. This makes sense when using `--always-copy`, so that your virtualenv becomes portable.

P.P.P.S. If you decide to use virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` and `pip`, and, let's say, you want to have `requests` package newer than the already installed one in `/usr/lib`, use `pip install -I`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages).

Comment: Thanks. This part especially was really helpful and enlightening: "Packages installed by pip in user's home directory have higher priority than system-wide packages, thus, they are taken first when doing import. In virtualenv, they are only imported if virtualenv was created with --system-site-packages option. Packages installed by pip inside virtualenv have even higher priority." :) I went with `--system-site-packages` for now, and in other situations when I'll have more time or will to make things cleaner I'll figure out what to do to make pip work for the more "special" packages too...