# How to run ipython from venv?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, ubuntu-15.04

My ipython works okay, but when I try to open ipython console from venv I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython3", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
ImportError: No module named 'IPython'
```

Any ways to do this?

Comment: that's using your system ipython - you sure you have activated the virtualenv?

Comment: @scytale, yes. Do I need to install ipython for each venv somehow?

Comment: in python 2, yes,  you'd need to do `pip install ipython` - I'm not familiar with python3 but I imagine the same applies

Comment: If you installed ipython from Anaconda, you can create and manage virtual environments with conda.

Comment: @pythad You need to [active the virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#activate-script) before running `pip install X`

Comment: @turtlemonvh, I've activated it, but ipython isn't a pip package(I installed it with `sudo apt-get install`)

Comment: @pythad That's probably the problem.  When you install python packages with `apt-get` they're always going to go into your main python installation.  If you want ipython running in a virtualenv, you can't use `apt-get` to install it.  There are ways to [pick up the main installation of a package in your virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages), but it's probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance create the `venv` with the `--system-site-packages` flag and install `ipython` with `pip`? This combination is broken in my experience (`Python 3.6.2`, `pip 9.0.1`).

Two workarounds are:

1. Use `virtualenv` instead of `venv`,
2. Or use `easy_install` instead of `pip`.

With `pip`, scripts get the wrong shebang pointing to system python.

Comment: What is this I don't even. Well, this fixes it. But I am terrified that changing the name of the virtualenv from `venv` to `virtualenv` can have any effect at all.

Comment: It's more than a name change. These are two separate packages (that work slightly differently) for creating virtual environments.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that now it works. You should be able to achieve that:

```
user@host:~/ source path/to/venv/bin/activate
(venv) user@host:~/ python3 -m pip install ipython
(venv) user@host:~/ ipython
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.31.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.executable
Out[2]: '/path/to/env/bin/python3'

In [3]:
```

Note that I am using `python3 -m pip [...]` to ensure that the module are installed in the environment and not elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

have you activated your virtualenv and installed ipython into the virtualenv?

```
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
pip install ipython
```

Comment: Is ipython a pip package?

Comment: I am getting this:

   (.venv) $ pip install ipython3
   Collecting ipython3
     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython3 (from versions: )
   No matching distribution found for ipython3

Comment: @robguinness - the comments aren't the place for asking for help - please open a new question

Comment: Seriously? I've been around awhile on SO. I don't think this merits a new question at all. My question is the same as the OP, but when I try the solution in your answer, I get an error. Seems to me like a comment is appropriate.

Comment: @robguinness - that's not how SO works - nobody will see your question here except me cause this answer doesn't get much traffic. (I got a notification). I'm not about to provide 1 on 1 help. if you ask a new question it will appear in the appropriate places and will get seen. the comment's aren't the place to ask for new help.

Comment: I disagree. If I ask a new question which is very similar to this question, it will get marked as a duplicate. No one is forcing you to provide 1-on-1 help.

Comment: just pointing out that SO doesn't work the way you think it does. anyway good luck with figuring that out.

Comment: When I install Ipython using this metodo all the module installed before are no longer available from ipython