# Can I have multiple django projects in the same virtualenv folder

Tags: python, django

Another newbie to django here. I was wondering if it is recommended/not-recommended to run two different projects in the same virtualenv folder that have the same django version. To be more clear, is it necessary to create separate virtualenv everytime I want to start a new project when i know that i am using same django version for all projects. I am using python django on OSX.

Comment: It's not *necessary*, but it's certainly *a good idea*. For example, what if you later decide to upgrade Django, but only one project at a time?

Comment: thanks for your comment @jonrsharpe, i got it now :)

Comment: you can also have system defaults and use virtualenv to override just the packages you need changed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the situation. Suppose if your Project A need to use Pip version 17.01 to run while your project B need to use Pip version 18.01 to run. So It is not possible to use 1 virtual env to run multiple project but the downside of having multiple virtual environments is it consume much space & resource of PC.