# Stop pip installing dependancies already installed using apt-get

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, pip, apt-get

How do I make sure packages installed using `pip` don't install dependancies already installed using `apt-get`?

For example, on Ubuntu you can install the package Numpy using `apt-get install python-numpy`. Which gets installed to:

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I've noticed that when I install a package that requires numpy using `pip` for example, `pip install scipy` instead of skipping the numpy dependancy it installs again to a different location.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

What pip should do is skip any python packages installed globally, right?

Comment: Mhm, no. What you should do is stop mixing `pip` and `apt` :). You cannot expect a package manager to be aware of other package managers. Instead you should take care that you are not using two different package managers that try to install into the same prefix.

Comment: Don't mix `pip` and `apt`'s Ubuntu installations. Even if `pip` installs in the same directory Ubuntu will not know about the package and you may overwrite it using `apt`.

Comment: I agree with your comment, but this cannot be avoided sometimes packages on apt-get are pre-compiled so I want to use them for the install and some pip packages and not in the apt-get universe so I need the best of both worlds. Maybe what I should be asking then is how can I make pip install to the same location as apt-get, maybe?

Comment: There are other strategies to solve that problem: Many python packages that need compiling are available as binary wheels. You can choose to install these with pip instead of compiling yourself. Another strategy is to create a local `virtualenv` that is aware of the packages of its parent.

Comment: I've used virtualenv are you saying you can create one aware of packages install by ``apt-get``? Also, I would be very interested to hear an answer suggesting/show binary wheels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In key here is to prevent multiple package managers to install into the same directories.

One strategy is to create a `virtualenv` that is aware of the package of its parent interpreter. This can be done by using the `--system-site-packages` option.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python --system-site-packages py27
source py27/bin/activate
```

This environment will not be empty by default. You may want to compare `/usr/bin/python -m pip list` and `python -m pip list`.

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages)

---

For many (scientific) packages there are also wheels available on pypi. Wheels are already binary and thus need no further compilation.