# I get some error and problems when install "matplotlib"

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, virtualenv

I have get a virtual env on '/home/name/pyenv' for python2.7.9;
Now I want to install 'matplotlib' for it;
then I activate this virtual env and install 'matplotlib' as below:

- by command "sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib";
  (if delete "sudo", permission denied), it runs well and I find "matplotlib" is exactly installed, but it is for default python and not for virtual env(pyenv) ;
- by command "pip install matplotlib"

  ## I get error as below:

  ```
                  * The following required packages can not be built:

                  * freetype
  ```

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tYCFkL/matplotlib
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/caofa/odoo-9.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/caofa/odoo-9.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/home/caofa/odoo-9.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/home/caofa/odoo-9.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/home/caofa/odoo-9.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tYCFkL/matplotlib

I want to install it by method 1, but i don;t know how to install it for virtual env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when working in venv then try to used pip for installation for python packages ,sudo apt-get install normally using for root user of Linux. for your case you could try
pip install matplotlib==2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to install matplotlib globally then create your virtualenv **with** the site packages, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages) for someone with exactly the same problem, by using `virtualenv --system-site-packages` you can then activate your virtualenv and add additional packages, or update them, within your virtualenv only.

I am reasonably sure that you can even uninstall globally installed packages within your virtualenv without impacting your global installation but suggest you pick a small package that you can easily reinstall to test this on early on.

Comment: thanks for your advice;  do you mean that I should  apt-get install matplotlib in command windows; then" virtualenv somedir --system-site-packages"; then somedir virtual env will can use the matplotlib?  but I want to know whether we can install something by "apt-get install somepackage" only for some certain virtual env?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install` will do a global _or user scope_ install - as it is not a part of the python "ecosystem" it does __not__ respect `virtualenv.`