# Python 2.7 How to load a shared module on a virtual env

Tags: python

The [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) was installed to Ubuntu 16.04.1.

I would like to use the graph-too together with other Python modules which were installed on a virtual env.

Is there any way to use a shared module on a virtual env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your virtualenv with the system `site-packages` directory included; use the `--system-site-packages` switch:

```
$ virtualenv --help
[...]
  --system-site-packages
                        Give the virtual environment access to the global
                        site-packages.
[...]
```

You can change this setting by re-running `virtualenv` on an existing virtual env directory, and disable it again by using the `--no-site-packages` switch.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [virtualenv-docs/configuration](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#configuration) page for additional options/scenarios.

> --system-site-packages Give the virtual environment access to the global site-packages.
>
> --extra-search-dir=DIR Directory to look for setuptools/pip distributions in. This option can be specified multiple times.
>
> $ virtualenv --extra-search-dir=/path/to/dists
>   --extra-search-dir=/path/to/other/dists ENV

Also, you can try looking for the answer on stackoverflow, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages), *before* you post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for finding a duplicate post. Please leave chiding the OP out of your answer posts; that's meta chatter that's not part of the answer. Moreover, if you found a duplicate, please do flag the post as such.