# Running "flask" command in virtual env uses global flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask, and setting up a virtual environment. I have followed the directions for setting up python and pip in a virtual env. When I look at `which python` or `which pip` it points to my virtual environment. However when I look at `which flask` it is referencing the system flask. How can I make calling my `flask` command reference my newly pip installed `flask` in the the virtual environment?

Comment: With your virtualenv active you can  run the command: `pip install flask`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation of python modules when using a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423013/installation-of-python-modules-when-using-a-virtual-environment)