# Matplotlib not getting installed on virtualenv I setup with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, virtualenv

I have created a virtualenv with Python3. I also installed matplotlib on the system. So when I try to use it outside the virtualenv, the system finds the installation. When I do `pip list` matplotlib shows as one of the packages. However when I activate my virtualenv it doesn't show it under python3. I tried removing and re-creating the virtualenv and it doesn't work. I also tried installing matplotlib `pip install matplotlib` under the virtualenv and again not working.
Any recommendation how to fix the issue?

Comment: What does pip freeze show?

Comment: The answer to this question should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages

Comment: pip freeze shows all the modules installed when not on virtualenv. When on virtualenv it shows nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I found the solution in the other post to be working out. So marked my question as duplicate.