# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError when uploading virtualenv to IBM Cloud Functions?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to upload a function to IBM Cloud Functions with a virtualenv that has opencv installed. However, when I try to run the action in IBM Cloud it says:

```
{
  "error": "Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"/action/1/src/exec__.py\", line 43, in <module>
from main__ import main as main
File \"/action/1/src/main__.py\", line 1, in <module>
import requests, base64, json, cv2\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'"
}
```

I'm using the python:3.7 runtime for this. I thought this was a library issue since this runtime uses Debian Stretch and I've had problems importing opencv with the python:3-slim-strech docker image before since it didn't have some required libraries like libsm6, libxext6 and libxrender.

However, when I ran `apt list` in the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmfunctions/action-python-v3.7) that IBM uses for its python:3.7 runtime, it had those libraries included.

I created the virtualenv using the docker method shown [here.](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/actions-python.md#packaging-python-actions-with-a-virtual-environment-in-zip-files) The exact command I used was the following:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/tmp" ibmfunctions/action-python-v3.7 /bin/bash -c 
"cd tmp; virtualenv virtualenv; source virtualenv/bin/activate; 
pip install --no-deps opencv-python;"
```

I used --no-deps because [the runtime already has numpy installed,](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-runtimes#openwhisk_ref_python_environments_3.7) which is the only dependency of opencv and because with numpy included the zip file exceeded the 48MB limit to upload it to Cloud Functions.

I should be able to import cv2 with no problems but I still get the previous message. Any help would be great!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question and all the steps you used to demonstrate the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a virtualenv folder to include local packages does not automatically [inherit the global site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages) from the runtime. This can be enabled using the `--system-site-packages` flag when using the virtualenv command.

Change the Docker command to the following to make this work:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/tmp" ibmfunctions/action-python-v3.7 /bin/bash -c 
"cd tmp; virtualenv --system-site-packages virtualenv; source virtualenv/bin/activate; 
pip install opencv-python;"
```

*`--no-deps` is no longer needed as the numpy dependency is already satisfied by the global site-package.*

Following your commands with this updated Docker script now works for me.

Make sure you allocate enough memory to the OpenWhisk action. I had issues running the code with the default 256MB memory limit. Increasing this to 1024MB fixed any issues I encountered.