# Is a systemwide ipython installation for multiple virtual environments possible

Tags: python, ipython

is it possible to have a systemwide ipython-shell that is for instance installed with [pipx](https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx) and can be used with all virtualenvironments in the system? It seems a bit unnecessary to me to have to install it into all environments?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages answer  your question?

Comment: @TimRichardson, no it does not. i think i want to do exactly the opposite thing that is in the top-voted answer, i.e. use ipython that is isntalled system-wide