# What does it mean an installed application must be "visible" to a directory in linux?

Tags: python, linux, ansible, openstack

I'm trying deploy openstack using Kolla-ansible approach with [this guide](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html) using a virtual environment. while I write the command:

```
kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one bootstrap-servers
```

I get this error:

```bash
TASK [openstack.kolla.packages : Install packages] *****************************************************
[WARNING]: Updating cache and auto-installing missing dependency: python3-apt
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "python3-apt must be installed and visible from /root/my_venv/bin/python."}
```

I googled but didn't find anything helpful and I'm super new to ansible, openstack and linux.
What is the best course of action to take?

I expect the outcome to be something like this:

```bash
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=8    changed=0    unreachable=0    **failed=0**   skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python *package* can be installed in a number of locations. Different *virtual environments* are configured to search different sets of such locations, so some of these virtual environments may be able to find a package and others may not.

A virtual environment created in the default way will *not* be able to find globally installed packages. This is by design.

Your specific virtual environment `/root/my_venv/` must be able to find `python3-apt`. Even if it is installed globally, the virtual environment will not find it.

One way is to activate the virtual environment and `pip3 install` the package. It will be visible only to that virtual environment.

Another way is to install the package globally with say `apt install`, and then create your virtual environment to inherit global packages [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages).

Comment: Thanks. so doesn't matter where the virtual environment is created, it can never find globally installed packages?

Comment: By default no, it will not find global packages.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, an installed application must be "visible" to a directory in order for the user to be able to access it. This means that the application must be located in a directory that is listed in the user's PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. so the environment variables can access the PATH?

Comment: The <code>PATH</code> environment variable is a list of directories that the shell will search for executable files when you type a command.  If the command is not found in any of the directories listed in <code>PATH</code>, then the shell will print an error message.