# Modifying a virtualenv so that packages installed in global site-packages are available

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revert the `--no-site-packages` option with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371136/revert-the-no-site-packages-option-with-virtualenv)

I've created a virtual environment using the [virtualenvwrapper documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) as follows:

```
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
$ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
$ mkvirtualenv env1
```

It works fine for the most part, but I've run into a few Django issues that require me to install some global packages outside of my virtual environment. Once I've installed these packages, how to I update my virtual environment to pull in these new packages? Or do I need to recreate the environment from scratch?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This question is a partial duplicate of: [Revert the `--no-site-packages` option with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371136/revert-the-no-site-packages-option-with-virtualenv)

However since this question specifically mentions **virtualenvwrapper**, the simplest solution when using **virtualenvwrapper** is to simply use its [`toggleglobalsitepackages`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#toggleglobalsitepackages) command. It takes no parameters and affects only the active environment.

```
$ workon env1
(env1)$ toggleglobalsitepackages
Enabled global site-packages
(env1)$ toggleglobalsitepackages
Disabled global site-packages
```

Alternatively you can reinstall the *virtualenv*, reconfiguring it to have access to global packages, while keeping the packages already installed there with the command:

```
$ mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages env1
```

*(thanks to @Adaephon for the heads up regarding `toggleglobalsitepackages`)*

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to reinstall the *virtualenv* because *virtualenvwrapper* also provides the `toggleglobalsitepackages` command (since April 2011 with version 2.7).

Comment: $ mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages env1

Work for me thanks