# Running Jupyter notebook in a virtualenv: installed sklearn module not available

Tags: python, scikit-learn, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook

I have installed a created a virtualenv **machinelearn** and installed a few python modules (pandas, scipy and sklearn) in that environment.

When I run jupyter notebook, I can import pandas and scipy in my notebooks - however, when I try to import sklearn, I get the following error message:

```
import sklearn

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8fd979e02004> in <module>()
----> 1 import sklearn

ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I am able to import all modules, at the command line - so I know they have been successfully installed:

```
(machinelearn) me@yourbox:~/path/to/machinelearn$ python -c "import pandas, scipy, sklearn"
(machinelearn) me@yourbox:~/path/to/machinelearn$
```

How can I import sklearn in my jupyter notebook running in a virtualenv?

Comment: I think you have not started your notebook with the correct python executable. Its written towards the right of the page and there should be a dropdown. Check if it is the conda installable with the virtualenv and not root.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You probably have not installed jupyter / IPython in your virtualenv. Try the following:

```
python -c "import IPython"
```

and check that the `jupyter` command found in your `$PATH` is the one from the `bin` folder of your venv:

```
which jupyter
```

For windows users in a powershell console, you can use the following to check that the `jupyter` command in your `$env:Path` is the one from the `Scripts` folder of you venv:

```
get-command jupyter
```

**Edit**: if this is the problem, just run `python -m pip install jupyter` in your venv.

**Edit 2**: actually you might also need:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name
```

and then switch the kernel named "my-virtualenv-name" in the jupyter user interface.

**Edit 3**: maybe the `--user` flag in the last command is a bad idea:

```
python -m ipykernel install --name=my-virtualenv-name
```

Comment: Interesting, I don't have IPython installed in the virtenv, but running `which jupyter` shows its in `/usr/bin/jupyter`, Ill try pip installing Jupyter in the virtenv and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Nope, installing jupyter in my virtenv did not reolve the issue, I still get the error message: `ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'`

Comment: Actually, I created a new virtenv (--no-site-packages) and pip installed the modules I wanted - now it works. Thanks

Comment: > ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'

Then it actually did resolve the jupyter issue. You just need to `pip install scikit-learn` in your  venv as well.

Comment: the answer of @ClimbsRocks `Now run the kernel "self-install" script:

python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name
Replacing the --name parameter as appropriate.` solved the problem for me

Comment: Don't forget to switch kernel in jupyter.

Comment: `ipykernel install` works, but unfortunately adds a new kernel globally, i.e. on sessions not run within this virtual env.

Comment: Yep, that's a problem for sure.

Comment: Installing jupyter in virtualenv is not working here: it fails to connect to the kernel

Comment: If it's not working for you, try running `python -m ipykernel install --name=my-virtualenv-name` from within your activated virtual environment. Note: I removed the `--user` flag. This will install the kernelspec to the system directory. I'm not an expert on the topic, but I it seems to source the correct path when you launch jupyter-lab. Worked for me!

Comment: The last command returns `Installed kernelspec env in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/env` and does not solve the issue. `where python` gives the correct path.

Answer (score 51):

Another approach to take is to have one global jupyter installation, but to point to different kernels to run as the backend.

That approach is outlined here in their docs:
http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs

Copying below in case the link breaks:
You can use a virtualenv for your IPython notebook. Follow the following steps:

Install the ipython kernel module into your virtualenv

```
workon my-virtualenv-name  # activate your virtualenv, if you haven't already
pip install ipykernel
```

Now run the kernel "self-install" script:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name
```

Replacing the --name parameter as appropriate.

You should now be able to see your kernel in the IPython notebook menu: Kernel -> Change kernel and be able so switch to it (you may need to refresh the page before it appears in the list). IPython will remember which kernel to use for that notebook from then on.

Comment: I can see the kernel find and connect to it in jupyter, but it can't find my modules still. Ideas?

Comment: @climbsrocks yea, as Elliiptica has stated, I've done this and still not able import packages. Any ideas?

Comment: Running 
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name 
solved it for me.. Thank You

Answer (score 35):

To use Jupyter notebook with virtual environment (using virtualenvwrapper) plus packages installed in that environment, follow steps below:

1. create a virtual environment

   ```
   mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --python=/your/python/path your_env_name
   ```
2. Activate the virtual environment

   ```
   workon your_env_name
   ```
3. Install Jupyter and other packages

   ```
   pip install jupyter, numpy
   ```
4. Add a new kernel to your Jupyter config

   ```
   ipython kernel install --user --name=your_env_name
   ```
5. Done. You may now use Jupyter notebook under the virtual environment.

   ```
   jupyter-notebook
   ```

Disclaimer: the question has been answered but is hidden in one of the replies. I googled and took sometime to find the right answer. So I just summarize it so someone having the same issue can easily follow.

Comment: Amazing, this worked directly for me. In step 1 the --python flag was unnecessary for me (didn't know what to put there so left it out), also step 2 was redundant for me.

Comment: thats the real answer... the order is crucial to making this work.

Comment: launching jupyter-notebook from the same terminal where my env was activated did the trick for me..thanks!!!

Comment: Step 4 makes this a golden answer - thank you so so much!! Highly bookmarkable.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming that jupyter is installed on your machine, not on the virtual environtment.

Using a virtual environment with Jupyter notebook

VENV_NAME = "YOUR VIRTUAL ENV NAME"

1) `virtualenv VENV_NAME`

2) `source venv/bin/activate`

3) Add this package if not present: `pip3 install ipykernel`

4) Then execute this command: `ipython kernel install --user --name=VENV_NAME`

5) Now open up the Jupyter Notebook and in change kernel select `VENV_NAME`

6) To install a new package perform `pip3 install <PACKAGE NAME>` in your terminal and repeat step 4.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Where is 5 performed? In the activated VENV_NAME? why should I repeat step 4 every time I install a package??

Comment: I found this in the 'kernal' -> 'change kernal' drop down within the notebook that I was working in. 
I don't think you need to repeat step 4.

Answer (score 5):

Solution without adding a new kernel globally!!

1. create a new virtual environment by

```
python3 -m virtualenv envname
```

2. Activate your enviroment and install jupyter in it by

```
pip install jupyter
```

One thing you have to make sure before installing jupyter is that you don't have following packages already installed in it.

```
ipykernel             
ipython               
ipython-genutils      
ipywidgets            
jupyter               
jupyter-client        
jupyter-console     
jupyter-core
```

If you've previously installed them then first uninstall them by `pip uninstall`.

3. Install your desired packages in activated virtualenv and launch jupyter in it and voila!

Answer (score 2):

**Creation of virtualenv with python3 -m venv command**

I had the same problem as yours.
In my case I had created the virtualenv with the command

```
python3 -m venv ./my_virtual_env --system-site-packages
```

The problem was I could not install jupyter inside the virtual environment as it was already in the system-site-package (when you try to install it, it tells you "Requirement already satisfied").

To install jupyter, (and in a first instance pip, that does not get installed neither in your virtual environment with this command) but still have access to system-site-package you can run :

```
python3 -m venv ./my_virtual_env
```

Activate you virtual environment, run `pip3 install jupyter` (and `pip3 install pip`) and then turn on the option include-system-site-packages in the file ./my_virtual_env/pyvenv.cfg.

After deactivation and reactivation of you environment, you will have access to system site-packages.

**Creation of virtualenv with virtualenv command**

Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3374514/7085581) you can prevent the access to system site-packages by creating a file ./my_virtual_env/lib/python3.4/no-global-site-packages.txt,
and get the access back by removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've set up the environment properly as others have noted, make sure you have installed the proper scikit-learn package. You can check with:

```
pip list
```

If you see something like: sklearn 0.0.post1

You need to run:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

The following is depreciated and will not work:

```
pip install sklearn
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more self-contained solution. Step 5 is the what is different from all other answers.

1. Create the virtual environment

   `python -m venv envname`
2. Activate virtual environment

   `source path_to_envname/bin/activate`
3. Install packages (in the new virtual environment)

   `pip install scikit-learn jupyter`
4. Locate the `jupyter` exectuable in `path_to_envname/bin/`
5. Run the version of jupyter that is *inside your virtual environment*

   `path_to_envname/bin/jupyter notebook`

This way you don't muck up the "global" jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Those with VScode, can click Python version box on the right > "Select Another Kernel" > "Python environments" and select the one that has their venv path.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can still install jupyter inside your virtual-environment if you have created your virtual env using:

```
python -m venv --system-site-packages path/to/my-venv
```

Simply do this:

```
activate-your-env
pip install -I jupyter
```

And you are now ready to go

```
jupyter notebook
```