# Why I can import packages in my jupyter notebooks only when using `pipenv run papermill`?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pipenv, modulenotfounderror, papermill

In a project where I have to run some Jupyter notebooks, I created a virtual environment using pipenv and installed some packages (note that I used the `--site-packages` flag).

Although now I am now able to run the notebooks with `pipenv run papermill ...`, I cannot run them from Jupyter using `pipenv run` or `pipenv shell` because of some `ModuleNotFoundError` exceptions.

In particular, the modules that are note found in the second case are the ones installed in the virtual environment only and not inherited from global-sites.

Indeed, if I check the `sys.path` I can see the difference in the two cases: in the second there is no `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/...` entry.

Why am I having this issue and how can it be solved? (If possible, I would prefer not to pollute my `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels` with other kernels from virtualenvs).

Comment: Probably answered [at this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449814/running-jupyter-notebook-in-a-virtualenv-installed-sklearn-module-not-available)

Comment: @AndreiR. I can confirm that jupyter is installed in the virtualenv and the output of `which jupyter` is the correct path indeed. So unfortunately the answers in the discussion don't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449814/running-jupyter-notebook-in-a-virtualenv-installed-sklearn-module-not-available), you also need to make sure that the kernel is also under the venv:

```
python -c "import IPython"
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name
```

and then switch the kernel named "my-virtualenv-name" in the jupyter user interface

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, as I wrote in my question, I would prefer not to populate `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels`  with kernels from virtual environments. Are you suggesting that this is the only way of solving the issue?