# How can I open Jupyter Notebook in venv to make my drake work correctly?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, drake

I install drake via pip in venv and I want open files from course `underactuated`.

I start venv by typing:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Drake installed correct because of output of `python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'`:

```
(env) dmitriy@dmitriy:~/git/underactuated$ python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'
/home/dmitriy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/__init__.py
```

But when I try run it in Jupyter Notebook with Kernel `env` I have:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake'
```

How can I open Jupyter Notebook in venv to my make drake work correctly?

Comment: Glad this worked! Any chance you can repost this comment as a top-level answer, and mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I have not installed Jupyter / [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) in my virtualenv.

This is the solution: *[Running Jupyter notebook in a virtualenv: installed sklearn module not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449814/running-jupyter-notebook-in-a-virtualenv-installed-sklearn-module-not-available)*