# Module not found when trying to run `black` in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, code-formatting, black-code-formatter

I've created a Jupyter notebook inside of a virtual environment.

These packages are installed:

```
black==22.12.0
jupyter~= 1.0.0
jupyter-black==0.3.3
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions~=0.5.1
```

In my notebook, there's a button with a little gavel to run `black` code formatting. However, when I click this, I get the error message:

```
localhost:8888 says 

[jupyter-black]
 Error:ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'black'
```

I've made sure I'm using the kernel created inside this virtual environment.

Reading through the docs has not pointed out any obvious errors I'm making here. Any suggestions on getting `black` to run appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

Run something like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42454615/1569221):

```
python -m ipykernel install --name=my-virtualenv-name
```