Solver GLPK not found in Jupyter Notebook
I am using Windows 10. and MS Visual Studio code 1.94.2. I created a new virtual environment using venv, with python 3.13.0.
I further downloaded GLPK and saved it under C:. I added it the system environment as a variable. Using cmd (outside of MS Visual Studio Code) and executing "echo %path%", I find it listed.
Now, I open MS Visual Studio Code and open the terminal, activating the virtual environment. "glpsol --help" is not re-cognized (which is weird --> Q1: why is that?). So I add the path again in the terminal of the virtual environment: "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\glpk-4.65\w64". Now, "glpsol --help" is recognized.
I now install pyomo in the virtual environment, create a Python file, and execute the following code:
    import pandas as pd
    import pyomo.environ as pyo
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
    model.x = pyo.Var([1,2], domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = 2*model.x[1] + 3*model.x[2])
    model.Constraint1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = 3*model.x[1] + 4*model.x[2] >= 1)
    
    opt = pyo.SolverFactory("glpk")  # try also 'cbc', 'glpk', 'gurobi'
    log = opt.solve(model, tee=True)

--> Works well.
Now, I create a Jupyter notebook, same environment, and execute the same code. It does not work. Executing "!echo %path%" in the Jupyter notebook does not show the glpk path.

"!set PATH=%path%;C:\glpk-4.65\w64" does not change the path
variable. "!C:/glpk-4.65/w64/glpsol --help" works, "!glpsol --help"
does not (Error: cannot be found). "log = opt.solve(model, tee=True)"
gives "WARNING: Could not locate the 'glpsol' executable, which is
required for solver 'glpk'".

--> What am I missing?
I tried calling the glpk solver but it is not found.

"Now, I create a Jupyter notebook, same environment, ". That not being how things work is what you are missing. Just making the notebook there doesn't actually connect the kernel that will be backing the running notebook to that environment. I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/72484386/8508004 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74819315/8508004 may give you some more ideas. Consider those as just rough guides because I don't know how well the match your state at this point.

You may also with to see https://twitter.com/kolibril13/status/1779887288266133634 .

Regarding the environmental variables you should set it in System Settings-Advanced system settings which will allow you to define system and user environmental variables.

@Wayne: yes, I connected the Jupyter notebook to the kernel / I assigned the virtual environment. Also, even if I hadn't, I actually should see my globally added System path to the glpk-solver, shouldnt it? It seems to me that it's a problem of MS Studio Code + Jupyter in particular....

@AmaeuszLi: Yes, I added these path variables in the system variable/path list, both to the global system and my user profile. This was successful as, if I run a Python script, it finds the solver perfectly well. Just not in the Jupyter notebook. Very puzzling...

You might be able to see the globally added path if you queried things correctly form inside the notebook. But depending on how isolated what the set-up you produced is, the kernel itself may not respect that.
