Activated venv only pulls globally
I know I've seen these questions posted before, but none of the solutions were solving my problem.
I have a new macbook air m3. I tried to set up everything properly but i can't get my virtual envs to point to the virtual paths instead of the global one. ((I first messed up by not installing jupyter itself in the venv, but now i've done that too. I can open a new notebook with that kernel, but when i'm trying to use an existing file in the repo, it won't let me change the kernel to using the venv.))
I am trying to install pandas in a venv in python 3.13.
Inside my venv, I install pandas with pip3 install pandas, and I am getting what I expect. pip freeze returns
numpy==2.2.1
pandas==2.2.3
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.2
six==1.17.0
tzdata==2024.2

and which python3 returns
MY_REPO/venv/bin/python3

But I launch jupyter lab and try to import pandas and I get the dreaded ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
When I import sys and print(sys.path) it shows my default Mac python3:
['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python313.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload', '', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages']

I tried switching to point to homebrew's python first in my .zshrc file to see if that would work better (then deleting and reinstalling venvs) and its still the same problem.
Am i missing some super basic / fundamental step to make venvs work??? I'm driving myself crazy over here. It only works in my venv if I install pandas globally.

I guess you need to add the virtual envs as a kernel to jupyter and switch to that kernel..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449814/running-jupyter-notebook-in-a-virtualenv-installed-sklearn-module-not-available

Thank you both!! I did this though, and while it does work if I open a new venv kernel in lab, it doesn't work for files that i have downloaded and moved into the repo -- is there a way to make jupyter venv work even for those types of files or can i just not use jupyter? is there a better program?

Please don't clutter your question with "edit" sections. If info is missing, properly incorporate it into your question. Any edits are available as history anyway.

If you're in a venv, remember to use python3 -m pip3 install pandas, do not use the bare "pip3" command, that will happily run your global pip3 alias (e.g. give which pip3 a whirl)

Note that which doesn't always behave right -- in zsh it shows you what your shell would actually use, but in most other shells it falls through to /usr/bin/which which just tells you what's first in the PATH but doesn't know about aliases, functions, etc and so can be inaccurate compared to actual operation. Better to use command -v python instead of which python to have consistent behavior.

It really isn't clear what you mean by " I open a new venv kernel in lab, it doesn't work for files that i have downloaded and moved into the repo " you should probably post a seperate question in any case
