# How can I use a system installed python package within a virtual environment?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I am using jupyter notebook on an Ubuntu server. To connect from my local machine, I am using an ssh tunnel.

jupyter is installed in a virtual environment.

This server has a tensorflow installation that was compiled and installed from source using bazel in order to be compatible with specific hardware of the server. I want to be able to use that installation of tensorflow from my virtual environment.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: @NiallCosgrove Thanks, but I found an easier way. Simply removed the no-global-site-packages.txt file. I was searching for this since yesterday, but probably I was googling the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371136/revert-the-no-site-packages-option-with-virtualenv).

Simply had to delete the no-global-site-packages.txt file. Unbelievably easy!