# Global packages in virtual environment with different Python version

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is it possible to use globally installed packages inside a virtual environment that has a different python version?
The global Python version is 3.9.4, and I have created this virtual environment using `virtualenv` with Python 3.7.9. The method used is same as the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534343/17786040) answer.

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371136/revert-the-no-site-packages-option-with-virtualenv) question where the solution is to make this change in the `pyvenv.cfg` file.

```
include-system-site-packages = false        # change this to true
```

Making this change does not enable usage of globally installed packages. I suspect this has got to do with the paths written in the `pyvenv.cfg` file:

```
home = <path to Python 3.7 folder>
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.7.9.final.0
virtualenv = 20.6.0
include-system-site-packages = true
base-prefix = <path to Python 3.7 folder>
base-exec-prefix = <path to Python 3.7 folder>
base-executable = <path to Python 3.7 executable>
```

Is it possible to use packages present in the `lib` folder of the other Python version (that has been globally enabled)? Maybe by changing some paths in the virtual env folder, from where the path to global packages is taken?